# Obtaining a Dropdown list items and their dynamic ID using Python 3.x and Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

i have a simple problem i am trying to automate the testing of a website that has a lot of dropdown lists  that are populated dynamically. I wish to be able to obtain all of the ID's (They populate once every day, unless a new item that was not previously in the inventory is entered.) so i can make my script target the ID to test them.

I am fairly new to this, however some info i am using Python 3.x with Selenium and Chromedriver. If you need any more info please advice and i will respond as soon as able.

Last but not least sorry for the english, not a native speaker.

**Update 1:** Archived if you need it please tell me and i can post it again.

**Update 2:** Archived if you need it please tell me and i can post it again.

**Update 3:** I am not sure if this is relevant (although i think it is) the drop down list is not a select list, is class is class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_AssetRecoverySkin which may explain why it doesn't work with the methods previously described, back to the drawing board, as soon as i have an answer i will post it.

Comment: Need you to show us the HTML code

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: You are locating elements by XPath (which is least reliable way) but using IDs in XPath. When I switched from XPath to locating by ID/name/class/CSS/text (in this order), my tests became more reliable. I usually do not even waste time to talking people off from using XPath (free country locate as you wish) and just ignore such questions but for you I made an exception :-)

Comment: Question Updated. Fallowing your advice @PeterMasiar i changed the way i get the element, i will slowly change the way i get all my elements but for the moment is not my priority so it will be a slow process.

Comment: You always have the option of talking to the developers and asking them if there is a particular reason for using this way of populating the dropdown rather than using for example a list. If you explain that this makes your job a lot easier and if it makes very little difference to them they might just be inclined to make the change. Testers and developers are not enemies, we're here to make nice stuff together!

Answer (score 1):

Python, following it's philosophy of "batteries included", provides perfect [`Select()` helper class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

`Select` provides many useful functions, the one you want is [`.options()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options) - list of the options.

This is why I love Python. :-)

Comment: Question Updated, i am trying to follow your advice but i am having a human error (mine) in the fact that i keep getting an error on my attempts, thank you for the idea.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select // forgot to add this, the right address at least in python 3.x is support.ui (at least the one mentioned in the python/selenium page).